# How to pass additional parameter in visitor pattern without modifying element

Tags: c++, visitor-pattern

There is a code:

```
struct Element;
struct Handler;

//  need to pass Handler at the same time
struct Visitor
{
    void visit(Handler& h, Element& e) {}
};

struct Element
{
    virtual void accept(/*Handler& h,*/ Visitor& v) {
        v.visit(/* h, */ *this);
    }
};

struct Handler
{
    void visitElement(Visitor& v) { e.accept(/* *this, */ v); }

    Element e;
};
```

Is it possible to visit Element in such a way that Element could know nothing about Handler class?

Comment: Is storing a reference to the handler in the `Visitor` viable?

Comment: You may look at https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/design-patterns/4579/visitor-pattern/15127/visitor-pattern-example-in-c#t=201705302059295359874

Comment: @Vittorio I missed that. It is a solution, but not a very nice one because I have to pass pointer every time before visiting, like so: `v.setHandler(h); handler.visitElement(v);`

Comment: You may pass it in visitor constructor.

Comment: @Jarod I mean that handler object is different every time. Handler is some kind of wrapper for Element class and the Visitor::visit method should process data from handler too. The question now is how to automate passing of handler pointer to visitor.

Comment: Why not just call visit directly? `void visitElement(Visitor& v) { v.visit( *this, e); }`

Comment: I think, you pass reference to element's base and dispatch will not happen. In this case there is no sense to use visitor pattern at all.